# Patch method not working for id in nested model serializer

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have two models , and I want to update them. When I update a field except **ID** ,it works fine. However, I can not update **ID** field of matrix cell object shown below.Also, I see **ID** field in get method.

```
class MatrixSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    matrix_cell = MatrixCellSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Matrix
        fields = ["id", ......, "matrix_cell"] 

   def update(self):
      for m in matrix_cells:
          m.get("id") #this return None
          m.get("name") #but this works
```

```
class MatrixCellSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MatrixCell
        fields = "__all__"
```

Comment: maybe try with `pk` instead of `id`?

Comment: I tried but same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added     `id = serializers.CharField()` to my MatrixCell serializer , and problem fixed.

```
class MatrixCellSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = MatrixCell
        fields = "__all__"
```